# Process/record multiple audio input streams in Java

Tags: java, macos, audio, javasound

Working on a project requiring the analysis (speech to text) and recording of up to 10 real-time audio (microphone) input streams simultaneously and separately.  I'm most comfortable with Java, so my central question is if this is possible with Java Sound API (or other 3rd party lib).  But development is just beginning so if there is a better tool for this job I'm open to suggestions.

Development platform is MBP OSX 10.8.

Regarding audio input, I'd assume a bunch of USB microphones, unless someone knows of an appropriate device that allows separate simultaneous addressing of inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Java Sound API isn't the easiest to learn, but it is reasonably low-level and powerful. I've mixed more 10 tracks before, using .wav inputs, custom-made "Clips" (reading sound files from memory) and procedural FM synthesis, using software I was able to write as a Java programmer with intermediate skills and some basic knowledge about sound (but NOT an engineering degree level of sound knowledge).

I've not tried recording multiple lines, or recording at all for that matter except one "toy" program that takes an input wave and stores it for varispeed playback. That really wasn't much more complex than just uploading a .wav, so I don't know the answers to t your question. I do anticipate it will be worth a look at the TargetDataLine interface as a key tool.

There are various sound engines written in Java. A contributor at Java-Gaming.org ("nsigma") has done some fine work on a media tool/system called "Praxis". AH -- just found this link:

http://neilcsmith.net/software

He often answers questions on the "Sound" topic at Java-gaming.org, and has spoken of "JAudioLibs" (linked on the page above).